# How to terminate ping <dest> &

Tags: command-line

The command

```
ping <dest> &
```

causes ping to go to the background. It still prints output to the terminal, however. Ctrl-C does not stop it, only introduces a new prompt. How to stop it from the terminal?

Comment: In addition to the answers, there is a way to naturally limit `ping`'s iterations with a count — `-c N` — where N is a positive number.

Comment: @l0b0 Yes true, but I faced this particular problem, and it's actually related to any program where we might not know the execution time, or where it might not even be defined. So I mean to ask how to stop the process.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First enter `fg` into same terminal that your `ping` command is running (it brings the process into the foreground), then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to stop the process.

[image]

Comment: This works. I also realized that fg works if we have multiple background processes, by calling them to the foreground one by one.

Comment: Yep, that's how it works, you can use `jobs` to get a list of process that are running in background.

Comment: How did you make that image loop?

Comment: @phillipsk It's GIF, that's how GIF works ...

Comment: @Ravexina I think they were asking what tools you used to create it.

Comment: @Seth Oh... in that case, I captured the video using "Kazam" then convert it to gif using `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 14):

If it is your one and only background job you can kill it with `kill %1`. If not sure you can list all your background jobs with `jobs` and use `kill %<n>` where you replace n by the number of your ping job.

Comment: Also, I found out that n matches the number that is print out in square brackets when running the command.

Answer (score 7):

When you send a process to the background, whether by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> or by `&` at the end of the command, you get an output in the following format: `[index] process-id`. If you send multiple processes to the background, the index will keep incrementing every time.

For example:

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 41608
$ sleep 101 &
[2] 41609
$ sleep 102 &
[3] 41610
$ sleep 103 &
[4] 41611
$ sleep 104 &
[5] 41612
$ sleep 105 &
[6] 41613
$ sleep 106 &
[7] 41614
```

In order to stop a specific one, you can either use `kill <process-id>` or use `fg <index>` followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>

Example using the previous output:

```
$ kill 41614
```

or

```
$ fg 7
sleep 106
^C
```

Answer (score 3):

Launch a new tab of terminal, run:

```
$ pgrep ping
  2564
```

Then kill the pid using `kill` command:

```
$ kill 2564
```

Comment: I used kill in the same terminal too (though the output made it difficult to use). However, I was wondering what to do if I couldn't go far back up in the terminal to see the process id printed, so pgrep has helped, additionally.

Comment: When you use `pgrep` to search processes by name, you can also use `pkill` to kill them by name. No need to type/copy the process id and use `kill`.

Comment: This is useful to know, but for this question it's a bit of *overkill*. :-p

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach towards a continuous ping is to use -c option and enter the number of time you want it to run, that way it will stop itself after the desired count i.e. below ping will stop after 100 pings

> ping -c 100 192.168.1.1 &

Answer (score 0):

When you are root, it's simply `killall ping`.

Comment: Thanks for killing my ping session I was running on the same machine -- a coworker

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
kill -9 %%
```

and it will kill the current background process you're running.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the process that you put in background (for current session )  with `jobs` command 
After you run this command you will see all the process which are running on the current bash and on the left side of each process you can see some numbers :

```
[1]-  Running                 sleep 200000 &
[2]+  Running                 sleep 300000 &
```

You can simply terminate jobs (processes) by using `kill -15 n%` (n is a number that is in [[] sign )

`-15` is for terminating process nicely , if you want to force close the process, just use `-9` instead of `-15`
PS : It is obvious if you run a  command with root privilege , you have to run `kill -15 n%` with `sudo`

2) You can see all of the process that are running on the system with `ps -aux` and for seeing `ping` :

```
ps -aux | grep ping
```

The output is like :

```
root     2615  0.0  0.0  25828  1052 pts/0    S    02:12   0:00 ping 8.8.8.8
```

The second number (2615) is PID or process ID and you can terminate the process with

```
sudo kill -15 2615
```